Не сохраняются данные при отправке формы Django
Сделал форму регистрации на сайте. По нажатию на кнопку ничего не происходит. В терминале выдаёт строку 'fale'. Есть другой проект с точно таким же кодом, но там всё успешно работает
Перепробовал разные способы, ничего не помогает
forms.py
from django import forms


class Reg(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        label = '1',
        required = True,
        widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs = {
                'placeholder':'Логин',
                'class': 'ireg'
            }
        )
    )
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        label = '2',
        required = True,
        widget = forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder': 'ФИО',
                'class': 'ireg'
            }
        )
        
    )
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label = '3',
        required = True,
        widget = forms.EmailInput(
            attrs ={
                'placeholder':'Мыло',
                'class': 'ireg'
            }
        )
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        label = '4',
        required = True,
        widget = forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs ={
                'placeholder':'Пароль',
                'class': 'ireg'
            }
        )
    )
    password_confirm = forms.CharField(
        label = '5',
        required = True,
        widget = forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder':'ПовторПароля',
                'class': 'ireg'
            }
        )
    )
    

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from test_app import forms
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def reg(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.Reg(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username'],
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
            email = form.cleaned_data['email'],
            password = form.cleaned_data['password'],
            password_confirm = form.cleaned_data['password_confirm']
            if password == password_confirm:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, first_name=first_name, email=email, password=password)
                user.save()
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('prof.html')
            else:
                print('fale')   
    else:
        form = forms.Reg()
    return render(request, 'registr.html', {'form':form})

urls.py
path('index.html', views.index),
path('registr.html', views.reg),

registr.html
<body>
    <form method="post"  >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">Registr</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Что происходит в терминале vc.code при попытке регистрации

[29/May/2024 13:10:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 243
[29/May/2024 13:10:45] "GET /registr.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1311
fale
[29/May/2024 13:10:55] "POST /registr.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1404


Все-таки, не "fale", a "fail".Вы выведите в консоль ваши password и password_confirm и посмотрите, почему они не совпадают.

возможно недоступен registr.html файл. Проверьте правильно ли он именован в каталоге приложения

[29/May/2024 14:27:06] "POST /registr.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1404
('q',) "q"
Пароль вводил 'q'

то есть, у вас ('q',) и 'q'? проложите в вопросе модели тогда, что-ли

Консоль выдаёт такие значения(пароль и подтверждение пароля)
('q',)
q
Не совсем понял что нужно сделать с моделями

Ошибка заключалась в том, что поставил не нужные запятые при перечислении формы в файле views.py
Верный код:
def reg(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.Reg(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            password_confirm = form.cleaned_data['password_confirm']
            if password == password_confirm:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, first_name=first_name, email=email, password=password)
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('prof.html')
            else:
                print(username, first_name, email, password,password_confirm)   
    else:
        form = forms.Reg()
    return render(request, 'registr.html', {'form':form})

